# application config handling in php

Tags: php, configuration

I am planning to write a small php application and I was wondering what is a proper way to handle application data, e.g. the size for displaying photos. It might be a dozen of key-value pairs.

There should be default values but they might change occasionally. The administrator user account will be able to modify them.

Since config data might change, it seems to be uncommon to save that data in an array in a php file. I have read that one should consider a database. Is there any functionality or extension that makes the job? Or do I need to start from scratch and code it in a php class and write SQL?

Many thanks for your suggestions and ideas!

(Hope this question is ok for a first post :-) )

Comment: `Hope this question is ok for a first post` ... actually some of your code would help

Comment: It is totally fine to put settings in a php file. Other options are json or jaml, but including a php array is faster. And json does not support comments.
A database is only needed for often changing settings, or if you want to offer a UI for end users. If it is only you (or a team), you better use simple files.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Code is still developing. It is only me so I guess I will go with a file config.php. Is it good coding attitude to rewrite the complete file if settings change?